# Laravel blade `@auth` directive not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to pick the master blade template dynamically as per the current user roll logged in. (here it should go to the 'shopowner' auth block)

```php
@auth('shopmanager')
@extends('theme::Admins.shopmanager.layout.master')
@endauth

@auth('shopowner')
@extends('theme::Admins.shopowner.layout.master')
@endauth
```

but this always gives error as it tries to compile the 'shopmanager' master template. It is not going into the 'shopmanager' @auth block because it's not printing anything if I print inside that block.

It only works if I completely comment out that line.

P.S.:

This is the master `theme::Admins.shopmanager.layout.master` template file
which must not be loaded.

```
@extends('theme::Admins.outline.layout.master')

@include('theme::Admins.shopmanager.layout.common.header')
@include('theme::Admins.shopmanager.layout.common.left-sidebar') // The error throws from inside this view.
@include('theme::Admins.shopmanager.layout.common.footer')

@section('title-head', __('Shop Manager'))
```

I can wrap the `@auth` check around `@include` lines but the point is, this complete file should be skipped from the compilation.

Comment: I think you have typo on last line. It needs to be @endauth. Maybe you have an issue in your auth guards? Are you sure that "shopowner" correspond to one of the guards configured in your auth.php?

Comment: You have two role (1)shopmanager (2)shopowner. right??

Comment: @wau, typo i updated. but that was not the issue.

Comment: @Manisha, role is not some column name in table. i am using guard of laravel.

Answer (score 3):

> SOLVED

As per my learning, `@extend(...)` will always be compiled regardless of outer wrap conditions. so must be moved to dynamic variable based blocks.

```php
@auth('shopmanager')
    @php
        $masterTemplate = 'theme::Admins.shopmanager.layout.master';    
    @endphp
@endauth

@auth('shopowner')
    @php
        $masterTemplate = 'theme::Admins.shopowner.layout.master';    
    @endphp
@endauth

@extends($masterTemplate)
```

Comment: This should be marked as best answer, I was trying to understand why extends was ignoring my conditions (displaying both mobile and desktop version).
You totally saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code ,i hope this ans help you:

```
   @if(Auth::check())
      @if(Auth::user()->role=='shopmanager')
          @extends('theme::Admins.shopmanager.layout.master')
      @else
          @extends('theme::Admins.shopowner.layout.master')
      @endif
    @endif
```

Comment: I already had tried `if (Auth::guard('shopmanager')->check())` syntax before and still the same issue. tried your syntax also.

Comment: The error comes from one of the view which is included in 'shopmanager's' master template which we extending in above code. in that view the $user variable obviously can't be found and that's why we don't want to load the complete master view wrapper.

Comment: I think the problem is not here,but in master app file.

Comment: I have added the master template file too. but my point is.. why even it is going inside that to check the include files?

Comment: First you are check shopmanager role is available or not? try this and check anythink getting or not @if(Auth::user()->role=='shopmanager') dd(Auth::user()->role) @endif

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191202/discussion-between-amit-shah-and-manisha).

Comment: This is really helpful for me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multi-authentication that time try below :

```
@if(Auth::guard('shopmanager')->user())
   @extends('')
@else
   @extends('')
@endif
```

In my case, I'm handling manager, customer and admin with this code.

1. **Manager** : Auth::guard('manager')->user()
2. **Admin** : Auth::user()
3. **Customer** : Auth::guard('customer')->user()

Comment: This didn't work for me. I bet the @extend still goes for compilation regardless of the condition. check my solution which worked will explain it.

Comment: have you ever tried to `@include(..)` another template inside your master template(which is not logged in) and there print some undefined variable. you will catch the point.